# How to execute longclick in listview

Tags: android, delphi, listview, listbox, delphi-xe6

I want to press an item in the listbox and keep for a few seconds until a message box, but Delphi XE 6 has only the OnClick and OnDoubleClick events.
Java for android has OnLongClick method , does anyone know if there is OnLongClick for Delphi XE , or is there another solution ??

Comment: I believe you could use the *long tap* [`Gesture`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Gestures_in_FireMonkey). In the `OnGesture` event you could then wait for the `EventInfo.GestureID == LongTap` (or something like that; help is something I do not trust here).

Comment: It's hard to work out what you are asking about. The Delphi version is unclear, and hence the platform is not clear. Presumably you don't mean XE. Please fix the question text. You really need to be on top of these details.